# How to put multiple lines in NetTelegramBot KeybrardMarkup?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I'm making a telegram bot with c#.
I want to read a number of names (not more than 20 tough thy could be less) and give them to the user as keyboardMarkup. With a one dimensional array they go all in one line and it's unreadable. I wanted to make 4 line with 5 names so i tried a 4x5 array. But i get this error

Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'NetTelegramBotApi.Types.KeyboardButton[*,*]' to 'NetTelegramBotApi.Types.KeyboardButton[][]'

```
                        if (text == "/lista")
                    {

                        // Read a text file line by line.  
                        listapz = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("listapz.txt");

                        string selezione = "Seleziona il paziente:";

                        int i = 0;
                        int x = 0;
                        int y = 0;
                        var arrays = new KeyboardButton[4,5];
                        for (i = 0; i < listapz.Length; i++)
                            {
                            y = i / 5;
                            x = i - (y * 5);
                                arrays[y,x] = new KeyboardButton("$" + (i + 1) + " " + listapz[i]);
                                selezione += "\n$" + (i + 1) + " " + listapz[i] + "";                              
                            }

                        var keyb = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
                    {
                        Keyboard = arrays,
                        OneTimeKeyboard = true,
                        ResizeKeyboard = true
                    };
                    var reqAction = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, selezione) { ReplyMarkup = keyb };
                    bot.MakeRequestAsync(reqAction).Wait();
                        Console.WriteLine(reqAction);
                        continue;
                    }
```

any solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can create new one dimensional array for every line 
Then

`keyb.row(first_array) //you need get only values in python it will like keyb.row(*array)
 keyb.row(second_array) //and so on`

and add all keyboards in one `reply_markup=keyb`

Comment: I'm writing in C# not python